# Syntax error for init sql while starting a docker container with MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, initialization, docker-container

I've got a problem. I'm trying to run a MySQL server in a docker container. So far so good. Now I would like to run a sql-file on startup of the container for initial stuff:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1111';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
```

I'm adding the file in my docker-compose.yml with

```
volumes: -/mysql/home:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Also, in order to connect to my container remotely, I need to create another root user with the statements above!
These are necessary for my case. But all I get is a 1064 error `(MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax)` and I have no idea why. Syntax seems alright to me, I even deleted some lines to be sure. The error stays the same. Why?
Does Docker use a special syntax or something like that?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Couldn't you just set MYSQL_ROOT_HOST and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD  ([entry script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L225))  and MYSQL_DATABASE  ([ref](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L267))

Comment: Unfortunately that wont help. I also want to create some default tables for my database later, so I need the sql file to work...

Comment: Is init.sql a file or directory? Should be a directory if volume mounting. Which docker container version are you using?

Comment: Changed it to a directory, thx. Using version 3. Does this make a difference? Thought the version in the yml file checks wether my arguments are valid or not. The sql-File is executed on the start of the container...

Answer (score 0):

In docker container, `root` is the default user for mysql having **ALL PRIVILEGES**. So,

- you do not need to create `root` user & then do not set privileges manually.
- but you can specify password with **MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD** environment variable.

Anyway, your query (`init.sql` under `/mysql/home` directory) would like as:

```
-- CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1111';
-- GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
```

In docker-compose.yml, `volumes` generally synchronizes contents for **directory vs directory**. So, you need to remove file `init.sql` from `volumes` directive. So, the ***docker-compose.yml*** could be look like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1111"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
     - /mysql/home:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    container_name: mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I need the CREATE User query as I want to connect to my MySQL-container remotely. I’m aware that I could configure a my.cnf file manually. But even without this, a single create database query produces the same error... So thats the main problem here... Basic queries are not working at all and I dont know why.